# Unable to run a script within popup.html in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to make Chrome extensions, and I'm having problems attaching a script to the `popup.html`.

The `foreground.js` stores some words which I'm calling `labels` in the local storage using `chrome.storage.local.set()`. What I want the popup page to do is simply show these labels.
I know the labels are getting stored, as I've debugged that process and it works fine.

The `popup.js` code:

```js
function displayLabels(){   
    var labels = [];

    chrome.storage.local.get("labels",value=>{
        labels=value.labels
    });

    console.log(labels)

    var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv")

    for(var i=0;i<labels.length;i++){
        var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv")
        var textBox = document.createElement("h5")
        textBox.innerText = `Label${i}: ${labels[i]}`
        mainDiv.appendChild(textBox)
    }
}
document.onload=(event)=>{
    displayLabels()
}
//window.onload=(event)=>{
//  displayLabels()
//}
```

And the `popup.html` code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked the spelling of the key `labels` while storing it, it is correct. I have also set the storage permission in the `manifest.json`

The `displayLabels()` function does not get called. I tried a simple `console.log("hello")` in the first line of `displayLabels()` too, but that also did not work.

Comment: There is no `document.onload`. It is a `window` event. Yet im a unaware of how extensions work.

Comment: I tried window event too, it doesn't work either